# Unexpected result in an if statement

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, boolean-expression

This one really has me mystified.
I have a dictionary where I track counts of errors and warnings.
Well in an `if (...)` block, also pictured, I'm testing for 0 errors, and for some reason, every combination of code I've tried says that **errors count > 0** is true.

Here's some results from the LLDB console...

> (lldb) po violationCounts[@"errors"]
>
> 0
>
> (lldb) po [violationCounts[@"errors"] class]
>
> __NSCFNumber
>
> (lldb) p violationCounts[@"errors"] > 0 (bool)
>
> $2 = true
>
> (lldb) p ((int)violationCounts[@"errors"]) > 0 (bool)
>
> $3 = true

[image]

Why is this evaluating to **violationsCounts is > 0**

Comment: Read the documentation for `NSNumber` and you'll spot your problem. HTH

Comment: Dooohhh... the (int) next to the number threw me totally out of wack.  Didn't even notice the NSCFNumber further to the left, or even the [class] result.  I really need some sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is saved as `NSNumber`, It should be :

```
po [violationCounts[@"errors"] integerValue] > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `violationCounts[@"errors"]` is an `NSNunber` so it must be converted to a integer, not cast:

```
if ([violationCounts[@"errors"] integerValue] > 0)
```

All values in `NSDictionaries` are be objects.

To print it in the deugger it is not necessary to convert it because the description method will be called and that will convert it for display. But it is necessary to use "po" (print object) instead of "p" (print):

```
po violationCounts[@"errors"]
```